# React Router causes Redux container components re-render unneccessary

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

Here is my major code， `App` component is connected to Redux's store:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const { requestQuantity } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={PostList} />
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route path="/topics" component={PostList} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
        {requestQuantity > 0 && <Loading />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  return {
    requestQuantity: getRequestQuantity(state)
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

`PostList` component is also connected to Redux's store:

```
class PostList extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchAllPosts();
  }

  render() {
    const { posts} = this.props;
    return (
      // ...
    );
  }

  //...
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  return {
    posts: getPostList(state),
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    ...bindActionCreators(postActions, dispatch),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PostList);
```

When `this.props.fetchAllPosts()` is called, the `requestQuantity` in the global state will change from 0 to 1 (request starts) then to 0 (request ends). So the `App` will re-render twice. However, every re-rendering of `App` also causes `PostList` to re-render, which is what I don't expect,  since `PostList` only depends on `posts` in the global state and `posts` doesn't change in these twice re-rendering.

I check React Router's source code and find the `Route`'s componentWillReceiveProps will always call the setState, which set a new `match` object:

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextContext) {
    warning(
      !(nextProps.location && !this.props.location),
      '<Route> elements should not change from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). You initially used no "location" prop and then provided one on a subsequent render.'
    )

    warning(
      !(!nextProps.location && this.props.location),
      '<Route> elements should not change from controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa). You provided a "location" prop initially but omitted it on a subsequent render.'
    )

    //the official always set a new match object ignoring whether the nextProps change or not
    this.setState({
      match: this.computeMatch(nextProps, nextContext.router)
    })
  }
```

It is the new `match` prop passed to the `PostList` causing the Redux's shallow comparison fails and re-rendering occurs. I hope React Router's team can do some easy logic before `setState`, such as using (`===`) comparing every prop in nextProps and this.props, if no change occurs, skip `setState`. Unfortunately，they think it is not a big deal and closed my issue.

Now my solution is creating a HOC :

```
// connectRoute.js
export default function connectRoute(WrappedComponent) {
  return class extends React.Component {
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
      return nextProps.location !== this.props.location;
    }

    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  };
}
```

Then use `connectRoute` to wrap the containers used in `Route`:

```
const PostListWrapper = connectRoute(PostList);
const LoginWrapper = connectRoute(Login);

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const { requestQuantity } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={PostListWrapper} />
            <Route path="/login" component={LoginWrapper} />
            <Route path="/topics" component={PostListWrapper} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
        {requestQuantity > 0 && <Loading />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Besides, when React Router is used with Mobx, this issue is also easy to meet.

Hope someone could offer better solutions. A long question. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: I would agree with React Router team that re-rendering of the component should not be a big deal, it happens at every change of the state. Why don't you want this component to be re-rendered? Also in a case if there is really a good reason to avoid component re-rendering - your HoC approach looks quite good in except that you need to call parent `shouldComponentUpdate` inside your own method implementation and use parent's result as part of your own decision about update.

Comment: The `PostList` doesn't need to re-render, since it doesn't depend on the `requestQuantity` in global store and the current URL isn't change(still in the same page). Without React Router's `Route`, it works good. As to the HoC approach,  I don't need to call parent `shouldComponentUpdate`, the parent is `Route` which does nothing in `shouldComponentUpdate` .If it does something, maybe this issue will disappear.